# Silverlight: Returning value from synchronous method using Rx

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous, system.reactive

I am writing a simple Silverlight application and WCF Service.
I want to create a synchronous method that return a value.
The method itself, call an asynchronous method from WCF Services. After I call asynchronous method, I want to get it value, and return to sender.
I hear that Rx can solve this kind of problem.

This is my code :

```
    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string myResult = getMyBook(txtBookName.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Result\n" + myResult);
        // myResult will be use for another purpose here..
    }

    // I want this method can be called anywhere, as long as the caller still in the same namespace.
    public string getMyBook(string bookName)
    {
        Servo.ServoClient svc = new ServoClient();
        string returnValue = "";

        var o = Observable.FromEventPattern<GetBookCompletedEventArgs>(svc, "GetBookCompleted");
        o.Subscribe(
            b => returnValue = b.EventArgs.Result
            );

        svc.GetBookAsync(bookName);
        return returnValue;
    }
```

When I click btnCreate, *myResult* variable still empty. Is that something wrong with my code? Or maybe I am just don't understand with Rx concept? I am new to Rx.

**My goal is :** I need to get the result (*myResult* variable) from asynchronous method, and then used in later code.

Answer (score 1):

This is more suited to the `async`/`await` keywords than Rx. Rx is primarily for managing streams of data, whereas in this case all you want to do is manage an asynchronous call synchronously. You could try using Rx like so:

```
public string getMyBook(string bookName)
{
    Servo.ServoClient svc = new ServoClient();
    svc.GetBookAsync(bookName);

    var o = Observable.FromEventPattern<GetBookCompletedEventArgs>(svc, "GetBookCompleted");
    return o.First().EventArgs.Result;
}
```

However, if GetBookAsync raises the event before you subscribe, the thread will block forever. You could mess around with `.Replay()` and `.Connect()` but you should probably just use `async`/`await`!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that GetBookAsync returns immediately, and will return the value stored in returnvalue. When the data arrives returnvalue will be out of scope, and by then btnCreate will have finished.

U could use await on the GetBookAsync, so that it will wait for the data to arrive before continuing.  Don't forget that would mean u also need the async on the method.

Not a great example or use of either RX or await, but trying is how we learn!